# Writing an angular directive with asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a small app that uses the Instagram API. I'm trying to write a directive to display a list of the logged in users images. I have a back end api that calls the Instagram API and returns the results.

```
.directive('userPhotos', function($http)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:   '<ul class="user-photos">'
                        +'<li ng-repeat="image in images">'
                            +'<img src="{{image.images.low_resolution.url}}">'
                        +'</li>'
                    +'</ul>',
        replace: true,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){

            $scope.images;
            $scope.serviceURL = "/api/photos/"+$attrs.photosPerLoad;

            $scope.loadPhotos = function()
            {
                $http.get(this.serviceURL)
                    .success(function(response){
                        $scope.images = response.data;
                    })
                    .error(function(response){
                        // show error
                    });
            }

        },
        link: function($scope, element, attribute){
            $scope.loadPhotos();
        }
    }
})
```

This works in that it displays the images as desired once the result of the API call is complete. However, as I have defined a `src` attribute for the `img` tag in the template during the initial phase of the Angular process this is called and I get the following.

```
GET http://myapp.dev/%7B%7Bimage.images.low_resolution.url%7D%7D 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I'm still a bit vague on the process Angular goes through as it's putting a directive together but I think I understand that initially, for the ng-repeat region there is a copy of the contents of this region made to be filled once the `images` binding is populated.

Anyhow, can anyone advise how I could get around this?

Comment: Try using [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc)

Answer (score 3):

So to clarify... this was solved by changing the `template` part of the directive to...

```
template:   '<ul class="user-photos">'
                +'<li ng-repeat="image in images">'
                    +'<img ng-src="{{image.images.low_resolution.url}}">'
                +'</li>'
            +'</ul>',
```

Thanks! @madhead.

Comment: You may also want to look into [`templateUrl`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) vs. `template` if your markup gets any more complicated than a few elements.